# Google Feed API - Json Object null

Tags: java, json, api

I try to get feeds from google feed api. This is my code:

```
try{
        JSONObject googleAPI = JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(url);
        if (googleAPI!=null){
            if (JSONUtils.isNull("feed")){
                System.out.println("No Results from this source");
            }else{  
                JSONObject feed = googleAPI.getJSONObject("feed");                      
                JSONArray entries = feed.getJSONArray("entry");                                               
                for (int i=0;i<entries.size();i++){   
                    JSONObject rItem = entries.getJSONObject(i);
                    items.add(this.parseResultItem(rItem));
                }                        

            }                
        }            
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Cannot read url: " + url);
    }
```

The url is "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=" plus a query in the end. When I create the feed JsonObject, I try to print the size of it (feed.size()) and it's 0.

Also, i get a Error: net.sf.json.JSONException: null object for the line:

```
JSONArray entries = feed.getJSONArray("entry");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the URL? Need to see it

Comment: Can't debug unless I can see the full URL request

Comment: the url is exactly the above, and I have tried a lot of different words for the query (q=) . I don't think it is the url's rpoblem, i took the url from here: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide?hl=en#resultJson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what library you are using for the function *JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl*, if you tell me where to get it, i can test your example as you pasted it.

I've managed to rebuild your example using the library http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html.
This example is working fine

In the example i'm using any URL for testing purposes, maybe you want to tell us what URL are you trying.

```
try{
    String url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blog";
    String jsonData = getUrlContent(url);
    JSONObject googleAPI = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    if (googleAPI!=null){
        JSONObject feed = googleAPI.getJSONObject("responseData");                      
        JSONArray entries = feed.getJSONArray("entries");                                               
        for (int i=0;i<entries.length();i++){
            JSONObject rItem = entries.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("found one entry: " + rItem.toString());
        }                        
    }            
}catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println("Cannot read url: " + ex.getMessage());
}catch(JSONException ex){
    System.out.println("Problem with JSON: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

the only custom function in here, is *getUrlContent* that just receive a URL and returns its content.
If you give me more details, i can make this example more simmilar to yours.

As this example works, and the only library i don't know is *JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl*, maybe the problem is that library

Hope this helps

**EDIT**:
1) The error you mention in the comment is because, as I stated, I'm using another library for this example, you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm), but i think you won't need to do it because

2) thanks to your code, i was able to rebuild your example and i found that, at least in my example, as i don't have a "feed" entity in the response i get, there's an error just as you mentioned, i mean in line

```
JSONArray entries = feed.getJSONArray("entry");
```

but, your example when i try to get *responseData* and *entries* that in my case exist.
What is weird is that it exists line

```
if (JSONUtils.isNull("feed")){
```

that should prevent this from happening, well, as I found in [docs](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html#isNull%28java.lang.Object%29), this check javascripts nulls. Maybe your confusion is beacause you are reading [this doc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29) that is for the library i've used in the example i built!
So you should replace that line with this one

```
if (JSONUtils.isNull(googleAPI.getJSONObject("feed"))){
```

I've do it and it works correctly.
So, in a word, check that the response you are getting actually contains the *feed* Object.
If you still have problems, maybe you want to give me the URL you are querying.

Regards

Comment: Your code gives me error for the attr jsonData in the line :
    JSONObject googleAPI = new JSONObject(jsonData);

it needs empty constructor maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function:

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        }
```